# Electron opening multiple windows package.json tweak

Tags: node.js, electron, package.json

Here's my script in `package.json` file. It's opening multiple electron windows for some reason. How do i fix this ?

```
"startRender": "cross-env BROWSER=none npm run react-start",
"startElectron": "concurrently \"tsc ./electron/electron.ts -w\"  \"nodemon --exec 'wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron electron/electron.js'\"",
"start": "concurrently \"npm run startElectron\"   \"npm run startRender\""
```

My project folder structure is like this :

```
.
├── electron
│   ├── electron.js
│   ├── electron.ts
│   ├── ipcEvents.js
│   ├── ipcEvents.ts
│   ├── messageSender.ts
│   ├── socketEvents.js
│   ├── socketEvents.ts
│   ├── Utils.ts
│   ├── windowEvents.js
│   └── windowEvents.ts
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   └── manifest.json
├── src
│   ├── App.tsx
│   ├── index.css
│   ├── index.tsx
│   ├── react-app-env.d.ts
│   └── serviceWorker.ts
├── tsconfig.json
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how my script looks for the `electron with typescript and react`. Its better to have the compiled `.ts` file to a separate folder. I am naming it `build`.

```
"scripts": {
    "react-start": "react-scripts start",
    "compile-electron": "tsc --module commonjs --noEmit false",
    "start": "concurrently \"cross-env BROWSER=none npm run react-start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000  && npm run compile-electron && electron ./build/electron.js\""
},
```

And here is the tsconfig.json looks like:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "pretty": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": [
    "electron/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: can u please show the script to include auto reloading on file changes to *.ts files. Your scripts don't include auto reloading

Comment: Currently I am not doing any reloading in my code. Btw does the  above code solve the opening multiple window issue though ?

Comment: im looking for a solution that retains the functionality of the scripts I showed in my question and fixes the problem .

Comment: Current the above script reloads only for the react changes.